# Add bottom border and BG color using JQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, css

**My JS Fiddle**: **http://jsfiddle.net/kvHq7/**

I won't put the script on this page as it is very extensive and will take up too much space. Please visit the JSFiddle link I posted above.

Only will add the CSS code:

```
.displayresult {
    display: none;
}
#fname, #lname, #splabel, #addlabel, #pnlabel {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
#first, #last, #specialty, #address, #phone {
    border-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

What It is currently doing is, for the result that is being displayed, it's adding all the result into one TD which is causing me to run into some issues.

- The first issue is, I can't make the background color to separate the
  current row from the next and so forth.
- Second issue is, I cannot put a double border under each row of
  result as it's one row holding the entire result.

So how do I either edit the JS code and/or the CSS code to have the following result:
[image: end result]

As you can see the every result has the double bottom border and also, alternate TD BG is gray.

Comment: Because I commented out the other code, heres the update: http://jsfiddle.net/KedsY/1/

Comment: Side note: You can combine those two attributes. `border-bottom: 4px double;`

Comment: Aim to style the rows instead of the columns.

Comment: @JimmyRare The only thing is as per Jquery it's adding the total value and display it in ONE row, so that won't be possible unless I add each row through JQuery.

Comment: Are you separating the records by `<br>` !!!?? You can't do such thing in this structure of coding.

Comment: I think that's where the issue is. I am most likely going to have to create new <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> for each record using JQuery. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code and remove some part of it that related to the radiobox and jumpbox selection, to make the code clear.
 So, you can add that parts to your code by yourself later.

 Here is your working code: **[jsFiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/KedsY/7/)**
Here is your structure change:

```
var recs ='';
       if ($('.dSpecialty').is(':enabled')) {
            for (test = 0; test <= phyList.length - 1; test++) {
                i = phyList[test].specialty; //get all specialty in the array

                for (var iVar = 0; iVar < i.length; iVar++) {
                    if (i[iVar] == dSpecialtyVal) { //$(".dSpecialty").find('option:selected').attr('id')) { //if what's in the phyList array matches selection
                    recs += "<tr><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].firstName + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].lastName + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].specialty + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].address + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].phone + "</td>";
                    recs += '</r>';
                    $('.displayresult tbody').html(recs);
                    document.getElementById('errorsp').innerHTML = "<i>Match found</i>";
                    }
                }

                if (i == dSpecialtyVal)
                { 
                    recs += "<tr><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].firstName + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].lastName + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].specialty + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].address + "</td><td>";
                    recs += phyList[test].phone + "</td>";
                    recs += '</r>';
                    $('.displayresult tbody').html(recs);
                    document.getElementById('errorsp').innerHTML = "<i>Match found</i>";
                }
                $("#splabel").css('font-weight', 'bold');
                $("#fname").css('font-weight', 'normal');
                $("#lname").css('font-weight', 'normal');
            }

        }
```

and add this line to give `background-color` to odd `tr`s (better to see changes in jsFiddle):

```
 $('.displayresult tbody tr:odd').css('background-color','#EEE');
```

Comment: WOW your code worked accordingly!!!!
One issue is, the title label, "first name" "last name" "specialty" "address" phone" i always want it visible.

Comment: @SiKni8 Just remove the `.displayresult { display: none; }` so table headers it will be visible before the search is made.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M I updated so every TD will have the double line on the bottom but it's not working. http://jsfiddle.net/KedsY/5/

Comment: And another problem is if you choose "Red. Nuclear Medicine" it's also showing Radiology included in the specialty which it wasn't before :/

Comment: @SiKni8 jsFiddle Edited. I did this code to give you the idea of coding, besides It's your job to improve it and make it work perfect :)

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Thanks. I am still learning the JQuery language so getting help here and there and understanding the code is going a long way. (May I ask what did you update in the JSFiddle?) :)

Comment: This did the trick :) http://jsfiddle.net/KedsY/8/ (I do happen to know SOME JQuery lol) THANKS for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should add one row for each search result you get, and not simply adding them all into one td. 
Otherwise there will be no choice but adding clunky css to each "result term" and try to align the background to the others on the same line.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing... for the displayresult DIV, I can use Jquery to add each row under the title labels? What would be the best way to do that in JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

If you can put your results into different rows (instead of having all results contained in the same `<tr>` element) you can apply alternating color rows with the following `CSS`, and can expand on it to also include `border-bottom` attributes.

```
.displayresult tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ececec
}
.displayresult td{
  border-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-style: double;
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it's only ONE row and the data is combined to add in each column. which is causing the issue.