# display variable within JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery:

```
fname = "TEST";
lname = "THIS";
spec = "DOCTOR";
addr = "999 vern blvd";
phonen = "999.999.9999";

$('#resultTable tr:last').after('<tr><td id=first>fname</td><td id=last>lname</td><td id=specialty>spec</td><td id=address>addr</td><td id=phone>phonen</td></tr>');
```

The following is displaying only the variable name. How do I edit for it to display the values?

Comment: Use the [string concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators).

Comment: it's just a string inside the brackets, so the normal javascript string concatenation would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname = "TEST";
lname = "THIS";
spec = "DOCTOR";
addr = "999 vern blvd";
phonen = "999.999.9999";

$('#resultTable tr:last').after('<tr><td id=first>'+fname+'</td><td id=last>'+lname+'</td><td id=specialty>'+spec+'</td><td id=address>'+addr+'</td><td id=phone>'+phonen+'</td></tr>');
```

anything inside `''` is a string, therefore you need to use one `'` to stop the string, `+` to say you are adding something to the string , then the variable.
After it, you use `+` to say you will keep adding stuff on string and another `'` to start the string part again.

Comment: @SiKni8 Remember this is for Javascript also, not only jQuery (which is JS too lol). If you want to concatenate two vars without any string between, you can do, for e.g. `'string'+ fname + lname + 'more string'`

Comment: LOL... Thanks. Would you be able to assist me with something else?

Comment: @SiKni8 Well sure. If is an unrelated thing, you could try search first and then if you don't find, then create a new question. =)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427187/add-bottom-border-and-bg-color-using-jquery-css (Siamak did the code but left out the title labels which i want it visible at all time)

Comment: @SiKni8 added a comment on the answer there.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick:

```
$('#resultTable tr:last').after('<tr><td id=first>'+fname+'</td><td id=last>'+lname+'</td><td id=specialty>'+spec+'</td><td id=address>'+addr+'</td><td id=phone>'+phonen+'</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation

```
"<td id=first>" + fname + "</td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Concatenation is wrong. You are writing variable name as a string rather than using the variable values.

```
$('#resultTable tr:last').after('<tr><td id=first>' + fname + '</td><td id=last>' + lname + '</td><td id=specialty>' + spec+ '</td><td id=address>' + addr+'</td><td id=phone>' + phonen +'</td></tr>');
```

For more readeability you can do this:- [Test Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jEYFk/)

```
var newTr = $('<tr />').append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: fname,
        id: 'first'
    }))
        .append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: lname,
        id: 'lname'
    }))
        .append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: specialty,
        id: 'specialty'
    }))
        .append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: address,
        id: 'address'
    }))
        .append(
    $('<td/>', {
        text: phone,
        id: 'phone'
    }))
  $('#resultTable').append(newTr);
```

Comment: Thanks... it worked but unfortunately i can only pick one answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#resultTable tr:last').after("<tr><td id=first>"+fname+"</td><td id=last>"+lname+"</td><td id=specialty>"+spec+"</td><td id=address>"+addr+"</td><td id=phone>"+phonen+"</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is an interpreted computer programming language. As part of web browsers, implementations allow client-side scripts to interact with the user, control the browser, communicate asynchronously, and alter the document content that is displayed. It has also become common in server-side programming, game development and the creation of desktop applications.